# Nodejs creating v8 Context in a separate thread

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, add-on, embedded-v8

I am using `v8 version 3.14.5.9`. and that of `nodejs is 0.10.17`.

In my c++ addon, i start a separate thread and on that i try to create an object whose constructor is :

```
 class ConstructorRunningOnSeparateThread {
      v8::Persistent<v8::Context> context;
  public:
      ConstructorRunningOnSeparateThread() {
               v8::Locker locker;
        v8::HandleScope handle_scope;//(isolate_);
        v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> globalTemplate = v8::ObjectTemplate::New();
        globalTemplate->Set(v8::String::New("myversion"), v8::FunctionTemplate::New(NodeVersion));
        context_ = v8::Context::New(nullptr, globalTemplate);    
        //         ^^^^^-------------------- EXCEPTION HERE

        if (context.IsEmpty()) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating context\n");
        }
      } 
}
```

I am getting an exception at `v8::Context::New()`.

Please help.

Thanks in advace.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by creating another thread? You can't use another context from the same isolate concurrently. Only one context could be active at a time. And if you use locker on your thread, you also need to make sure node thread uses locker too.

Comment: How can i ask nodejs to execute my code in its own context ? Is there something to push my "task" on the Nodejs v8 main thread ?

Comment: If it is a JavaScript task, just use process.nextTick() to add a callback function to event loop. In case of C++ task you need to create native binding to be able to call it from JavaScript. More information here http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html

Comment: It is like my addon want to execute simple javascript `"var fs=require ('fs');"` How i do it from c++ addon ?